# CORS error, when i use instagram API with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, instagram

I have simple task - get users' data from instagram account. I use standard instagram api and angularjs.

Here is controllers' request method:

```
 $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/6976008122/media/recent/?access_token=1030475459.50cd673.aa04db13898d4fsd9ff8fe5095b32f34&scope=public_content&count=4'
    }).then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

But I always get this error message:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://project.loc' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 405.

The first few pages of Google search has not helped, please help me understand and solve this problem.

Comment: The error is quite verbose, you make a request from host that's not allowed.

Comment: As as already pointed out by @nweg use Jsonp .

Comment: @OP by the way, you may not want your access token readily available like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jsonp, there's a good example located here:  [JSONP Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505596/instagram-jquery-ajax-type-get-cant-get-around-cors)

Here's a link to another Stack Overflow question that explains how to do jsponp with angular [Angular Jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916362/angularjs-how-to-make-a-jsonp-request)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i use angulars' $http.jsonp methos and this solved the problem.